# Problems with java and reading data from a CD drive in linux

Tags: java, ripping

I have been trying to write a simple audio ripper that i can use to learn how diffrent CODEC's work but i have got stuck on the first step, i cant get my program to read from the CD, the folowing code is what i have been trying to use

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class learning 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {   
        File cd = new File( "/dev/sr0" );
        RandomAccessFile rawAccess = new RandomAccessFile( cd, "r" );
        byte[] content = new byte[20];
        rawAccess.seek(19613);
        rawAccess.readFully(content);

        System.out.println(content);
    }

}
```

but it gives me the folowing error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:355)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:414)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:394)
    at learning.main(learning.java:21)
```

and i cant figure out why i get this, i though maby RandomFileAccess wasn't the right class to use but the only thing i could find said this should work

Any help on how to read CD's from java would be much appreciated.

Cheers Daniel

Comment: Is your CD mounted and accessible through `/dev/sr0`?

Comment: yes im sure it is, i ran "cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -toc", which is meant to print out the Table Of Contents of the CD and it dident give any errors

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should mount on a directory which the user logged in the OS Linux have access. E.g. : /mnt/cdrom or /media/cdrom

After that open your mp3 file or audio file :

```
File cd = new File( "/dev/sr0/track1.mp3" );
```

or

```
File cd = new File( "/dev/sr0/track1.dat" );
```

(don't forget the extension of the Audio or Mp3 file).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the same, but I suspect it will get you going...

[Is there a platform independent way (Java?) to read an audio CD's TOC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693/is-there-a-platform-independent-way-java-to-read-an-audio-cds-toc)

If you don't want to use the built in stuff (for educational reasons), http://www.tritonus.org/ is open source so you might be able to look at how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a related problem and answer that is pertinent to your problem: [Mount and unmount hard drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505682/mount-and-unmount-hard-drives)

According to the linked question and accepted answer, **the answer is both "Yes" and "No".** You can provide a Java API that use adapter pattern for native interface, but you will also have to do a number of things, **thus making the solution not purely Java, but a hybrid:**

- create Java interfaces that support mount/unmount commands create
- classes that implements interfaces as native methods create native
- implementations of this commands in C or other language. One
- implemantation for OS (Win, Mac, Linux) pack it to one jar build
- small factory that provide implementation of interface and load
  native libraries

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/sr0` is directory, then there is a problem. Please try passing one of the audio files as parameter e.g.

```
        File cd = new File( "/dev/sr0/track1" );
```

That should be working.

Comment: When i try that it gives me an error for the line "RandomAccessFile rawAccess = new RandomAccessFile( cd, "r" );" saying that it isn't a directory